# Angular2 and D3.js Gantt chart

Tags: d3.js, angular, typescript

I have an angular2 app which i am attempting to implement a Gantt chart from d3.js into. I am trying to use the following example http://bl.ocks.org/dk8996/5538271. obviously this uses javascript rather than typescript. However i have got most of it seeming ok, but i get one issue.

Here is my whole method:

```
createSchedule() {
    var tasks = [{"startDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 01:36:45 EST 2012"),"endDate":new Date("Sun Dec 09 02:36:45 EST 2012"),"taskName":"E Job","status":"RUNNING"}];
    var taskStatus = {
        "SUCCEEDED" : "bar",
        "FAILED" : "bar-failed",
        "RUNNING" : "bar-running",
        "KILLED" : "bar-killed"
    };

    var taskNames = [ "D Job", "P Job", "E Job", "A Job", "N Job" ];

    tasks.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.endDate.getTime() - b.endDate.getTime();
    });

    var maxDate = tasks[tasks.length -1].endDate;
    tasks.sort(function(a,b) {
        return a.startDate.getTime() - b.startDate.getTime();
    });
    var minDate = tasks[0].startDate;

    var format = "%H:%M";
    var timeDomainString = "1day";

    var gantt = d3.gantt().taskTypes(taskNames).taskStatus(taskStatus).tickFormat(format).height(450).width(800);
    gantt.timeDomainMode("fixed");
    changeTimeDomain(timeDomainString);

    gantt(tasks);

    function changeTimeDomain(timeDomainString) {
        this.timeDomainString = timeDomainString;
        switch (timeDomainString) {
        case "1hr":
        format = "%H:%M:%S";
        gantt.timeDomain([ d3.time.hour.offset(new Date(getEndDate()), -1), getEndDate() ]);
        break;
        case "3hr":
        format = "%H:%M";
        gantt.timeDomain([ d3.time.hour.offset(new Date(getEndDate()), -3), getEndDate() ]);
        break;

        case "6hr":
        format = "%H:%M";
        gantt.timeDomain([ d3.time.hour.offset(new Date(getEndDate()), -6), getEndDate() ]);
        break;

        case "1day":
        format = "%H:%M";
        gantt.timeDomain([ d3.time.day.offset(new Date(getEndDate()), -1), getEndDate() ]);
        break;

        case "1week":
        format = "%a %H:%M";
        gantt.timeDomain([ d3.time.day.offset(new Date(getEndDate()), -7), getEndDate() ]);
        break;
        default:
        format = "%H:%M"

        }
        gantt.tickFormat(format);
        gantt.redraw(tasks);
    }

    function getEndDate() {
        var lastEndDate = Date.now();
        if (tasks.length > 0) {
            lastEndDate = tasks[tasks.length - 1].endDate.getTime();
        }
        return lastEndDate;
    }

}
```

The bit where i get the error is:

```
var gantt = d3.gantt().taskTypes(taskNames).taskStatus(taskStatus).tickFormat(format).height(450).width(800);
```

It says `Property 'gantt' does not exist on type 'typeof d3'`

I import my d3 as follows

`import * as d3 from 'd3';`

I dont have any errors anywhere else and i am struggling to track down the issue.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Also as a test to make sure d3 is working i implement a simple circle as follows:

`d3.select("#scheduleDiv").append("svg").attr("width",50).attr("height", 50).append("circle").attr("cx", 25).attr("cy", 25).attr("r", 25).style("fill", "purple");`

This works fine but the .gantt() does not

Comment: `gantt()` method is not part of the d3 library. It is important from `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.mentful.com/gantt-chart-d3v2.js"></script>` in your example

Comment: ah ok i didnt realise that. so as i am building the chart in my component ts file, where is the best place to import that script?

Comment: If you have the specific typing files defined and the script tags in your index.html, you dont need to import them anywhere actually.

Comment: I have the d3 typings installed but its in modules not global is that an issue? and ive imported that script into the index.html however it fails to compile because of the error as that hasnt gone away

Comment: Apologies if im being simple or naive im still fairly new to Angular2 and TS

Comment: you have to define gantt() method in the d3 module too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126712/discussion-between-daroga-and-echonax).

Comment: DaRoGa, I am trying to implement d3-gantt-chart in an Angular 4 application I am building and am struggling to use the module which I have installed using NPM. Can I chat to discover your solution please?

Comment: @TDC I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are having that error because `gantt()` method is not part of the d3 library. It is imported from 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.mentful.com/gantt-chart-d3v2.js">
</script‌​>` in your example.

If you can find the definition file of the gantt library you can add it. If not, you have to create a custom one like:

```
declare module d3 {
    export function gantt(input:any, input2:any): any;

}
```