# Typescript 'is not a module' error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Angular2 project where i need to import a javascript file for use in my typescript.

I have a javascript file in app/js/d3gantt.js which contains a single function of `gantt = function()`.

```
gantt = function() {
    //Does lots of stuff
    return gantt;
};
```

I then have a definition file called d3gannt.d.ts in the same folder which looks like this:

```
declare module 'd3Gantt' {
    export module d3Gantt {
        export function gantt(): any;
    }
}
```

And then i reference it in my component as 
`import * as d3Gantt from '../app/js/d3gantt';`

However, i get the error message stating `File 'c:/Projects/RepackLog/RepackLog/RepackLog/app/js/d3gantt.d.ts' is not a module`

Am i missing something that is needed for this to pick up my files properly?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to export, `export gantt;`  on your **app/js/d3gantt.js **

Comment: OK where do i put it and whats the syntax? ive put my js file in question removing the contents of the function so they dont get in the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @FabioAntunes mentioned in one of the comments above, you just have to export `gantt` on your d3gantt.js file itself, in-line.
The exact syntax would be

```
export gantt = function() {
    //Does lots of stuff
    return gantt;
};
```

No need to declare it anywhere else.
For further note on exporting modules please refer this post ([Typescript es6 import module "File is not a module error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805559/typescript-es6-import-module-file-is-not-a-module-error/32805764#32805764)).

Answer (score 1):

Declare module as below :

```
declare module 'd3Gantt' {
  export function gantt(): any;    
}
```

Then import module as : `import * from 'path to your module file'` or `import * as d3 from 'path to your module file'`

Comment: change file name to `d3gantt.ts` and check again

Comment: the javascript file?

Comment: you are importing with `import * as d3Gantt from '../app/js/d3gantt' ` and you have said that `app/js/d3gantt` is `app/js/d3gantt.d.ts` so change its name to `d3gantt.ts`

Comment: no it didnt work. am i missing something to be able to map a javascript file to typescript

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259765/angular2-and-d3-js-gantt-chart also may it will help you